Type name error: The type name is unknown
When I try to compile my C++ program I get
error: unknown type name 'consteval'
consteval int get_value(){
^
1 error generated.
I am using vs code on Mac OS with C++ 17? So shouldn't it recognize this type name??
Any advice would be appreciated thankyou
I checked the command pallet to see if it was the wrong version but it was C++ 17 and for C++11 or later versions this should be recognized.

Please add your code (minimal reproducible example) and compile flags - otherwise it's hard to guess what's happening here :)

Actually it's pretty easy to figure out this one even with the limited information provided. Looking at some good documentation like cppreference would have cleared the problem up almost instantly.

Reading documentation is a major part of programming. Once you read the documentation for consteval you'll see that it is a c++20 feature. C++20 consteval functions and what is consteval should tell you this. See also How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

consteval is C++20, not C++17...

Why is this answer downvoted? He is right!. since C++20 as the C++ wiki in the link says.

No, it does provide an answer to the question. And the right answer, too.

@user4581301 granted, it's something like the shortest answer in the history of answers; but, I don't have a Mac or "VS code", so it lacks a suggestion how to enable C++20. I don't even know whether clang takes the same kind of -std=c++20 options that g++ does... there's definitely some room for improvement...

My thinking: If the asker knows how to turn on C++17 or C++11 in their tools, they know how to turn on C++20.
